# C_CPP.intellisense disabled. How to enable again

Tags: intellisense

An extension I had tried in Visual-Studio code appears to have disabled C/C++ intellisense. It can't be turned on again. Modifying the setting in the settings dialog has no effect [evidence:  switch source/header leads to a pop up message stating C_CPP.intellisense is set to disabled.].

Spent now several hours on this, the setting even survives uninstalling the software, purging all (known) vs-code related directories or starting a thermonuclear war.

I am getting a bit desperate here. Here are my questions:

- Is there a way to wipe everything (short of reinstalling the entire machine)?
- Where is the authoritative setting for C-CPP.intellisense? Entry occurs in several locations (User/Remote/....). Is there a priority?
- What other mechanisms could interfere with this setting?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the effect involved from default setting.json in below directory

C:\Users\chanli\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json

try add
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "Default"

Comment: Please replace your path with %AppData%\Code\User\settings.json and indicate that it is a windows vscode path.

Comment: had to change it to all lowercase 
"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default"

Answer (score 0):

settings -> in search bar search this: C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine
for me it was "disable" . for solve error set it "default".
after that in any .cpp file click on yellow lamp and change the compiler path to C:\ .... \gcc.exe ( i think any of them are ok to choose )

sorry for my bad english