# VSC Autocompletion and colorization of code not working (Extensions already installed)

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'am using VSC and started programming c++. But somehow the autocompletion and coloring of the code is not working properly. I have the latest version of VSC and already reinstalled the extensions. I have no clue what could cause the problem, I would be very grateful if you guys could help me. For example "x1", "x2" and "epsilon" in the body of the function should be colored blue and not white and I think this problem links or correlates to the autocompletion problem.

[image: My extensions that I use]

[image: An coding example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of desperately searching for a solution, I've found this, which actually solved my problem.

[Solution to my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889739/c-cpp-intellisense-disabled-how-to-enable-again)